# binary search not working and producing wrong output

Tags: java, binary-search

```
static int bSearch(int[] a, int lo, int hi, int key)
    {
        
            if (hi>=lo && lo<a.length-1)
            {  
            int mid = (hi+lo)/2;

            if (a[mid] == key){
                return mid;
            }
            
            if (a[mid] > key){
                return bSearch(a, lo, mid-1, key);
            }
            if ( a[mid] < key ){
                return bSearch(a, mid+1, hi, key);
            }

            }
    return -1;

    }
```

this is my code ^

and this is my input file: 100 89 65 46 32 90 50 38 67 71 42 92 99 57 90 89 98 34 85 19 60 15 99 79 57

I need the code to sort the array from lowest to highest using binary search but i keep getting this wrong output: 57 79 99 15 60 19 85 34 98 90 57 99 92 42 71 67 38 50 90 32 46 65 89 100

and this is the rest of the code, but what I'm working on fixing is the part above, because i cannot change anything in the original code below

```
public class BSrecursive
{
    static final int INITIAL_CAPACITY = 5;

    public static void main( String args[] ) throws Exception
    {
        if (args.length < 1 )
        {
            System.out.println("ERROR: Must put input filename on cmd line\n");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        Scanner infile = new Scanner( new File( args[0] ) );

        int[] arr = new int[INITIAL_CAPACITY];
        int count= 0;

        while ( infile.hasNextInt() )
        {
            if ( count==arr.length ) arr = upSizeArr(arr);
            if (insertInOrder( arr, count, infile.nextInt() ) )
             ++count;
        }

        arr=trimArr(arr,count); // Now count == .length
        printArray( arr );  // we trimmed it thus count == length so we don't bother to pass in count

    }

    // ############################################################################################################

    static void printArray( int[] arr  )
    {
        for( int i=0 ; i<arr.length ;++i )
            System.out.print(arr[i] + " " );
        System.out.println();
    }

    static int[] upSizeArr( int[] fullArr )
    {
        int[] upSizedArr = new int[ fullArr.length * 2 ];
        for ( int i=0; i<fullArr.length ; ++i )
            upSizedArr[i] = fullArr[i];
        return upSizedArr;
    }

    static int[] trimArr( int[] oldArr, int count )
    {
        int[] trimmedArr = new int[ count ];
        for ( int i=0; i<count ; ++i )
            trimmedArr[i] = oldArr[i];
        return trimmedArr;
    }

    // REMOVE ALL COMMENTS FROM INSERT IN ORDER JUST BEFORE HANDIN
    static boolean insertInOrder( int[] arr, int count, int newVal )
    {
        int index = bSearch( arr, 0, count-1, newVal );
        if ( index >= 0 ) return false; 

        index = -(index+1);

        for ( int i=count-1 ; i>=index ; --i ) 
            arr[i+1] = arr[i];

        arr[index] = newVal;
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: it is already sorted above` static boolean insertInOrder( int[] arr, int count, int newVal )
    {
        int index = bSearch( arr, 0, count-1, newVal );
        if ( index >= 0 ) return false; 

        index = -(index+1);

        for ( int i=count-1 ; i>=index ; --i ) 
         arr[i+1] = arr[i];

        arr[index] = newVal;
        return true;
    }`.

Comment: OK, a couple of things.  Your `bSearch` method returns `-1` whenever the `key` is not found.  But that's not what you want - you want it to return the  position in the array where the `key` _should_ be inserted.  Also, you have `index = -(index+1);` in the insertion code - that's not right either.  Once you've fixed `bSearch` so that it finds the right place to insert the `key`, you don't want to swap `index` out for a negative number (or you'll get an index out of bounds exception).

Comment: The way your code is working at the moment, `bSearch` will nearly always return `-1`, and then you're just inserting the new entry at the beginning of the array every time.  The effect of that will just be to reverse the order of the array elements

Comment: right but the only part that i'm asked to edit is the last binary search part, so i can't change the index

Comment: Well, at the very least, you'll need to change `if ( index >= 0 ) return false; ` in the `insertInOrder` method.  Otherwise, once you've found the place to insert the key, you still won't insert it.  I suppose you could do something unusual like making the `bSearch` method return a negative number to represent a place in the array where the key could be inserted, but that would be a very counter-intuitive way to design this.

Answer (score 0):

So i just changed the return statement from `return -1;` to `return -(mid+1);` and now it produces the correct output